# How can we monitor for more than 20 regions in iBeacon protocol?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ibeacon, eddystone

I am making an react native app that uses regions intensively, we make a service in background where we fetch region list from internet and monitor for those regions. But I ran into errors when I tried to monitor more than 20 regions. In my case every venue has multiple beacons, thus multiple regions used up in one venue. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: 20 regions is a hard limit on ios. You typically use the same major in a given area so that you can monitor fewer regions until you get a region entry and then you can range for the specific beacon and/or create specific regions for nearby beacons

Comment: But every beacon differs in triggering actions so I need to identify, I tried monitoring by providing only uuid and identifier, but I did not get major and minor in response so that I could differentiate between that, that happens only in ranging

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question: You can't

> An app can register up to 20 regions at a time. In order to report
>   region changes in a timely manner, the region monitoring service
>   requires network connectivity.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423656-startmonitoring

But now, maybe there is a way to unregister / register base on location update... If you are in Europe, maybe it's pointless to register for Region in America (you get the spirit)... so you can use location update to register only to the region near you.

Comment: So I need to locate user's location and then fetch relative UUIDs from my server and monitor?

Comment: That's what I would do, register for significant change in location, then ask my server what are the "regions" around me - or do so in-app by distance calculation based on lat/long -, unregister from all previous regions and register to the received region.

Comment: If you consider shops in a city, while being in a city itself it may exceed 20 I guess, and in my case every shop may have more than one beacon

Comment: For something as small and packed as shops can be, for example in a mall, it can indeed be difficult. but again, once you are detecting one, you know where your user is and you can only monitor for the neighbours.

Comment: And location updates can give you the user location up to 200 meters if I recall, so you register for the region only in a short radius (like 500 meters / 0,3 miles)

Comment: Great thanks let me try that! But both of these tasks together wouldnt that consume a lot of battery?